# Agregar valores a lista de listas

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un script en un ciclo For que arma una lista de listas con los resultados de mi busqueda.
A cada lista necesito agregar un valor "variable".
Este es mi codigo:

```
root = ET.fromstring(resp)
data = root.findall('.//row')
for datum in data:
    entries = datum.findall('.//col')
    datos.append([entry.text.strip()
                        for entry in entries[:5]])
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
[['peras', '20', 'Acme'], ['bananas', '35', 'Zero'], ['sandias', '45', 'Lion']]
```

Quiero obtener el siguiente resultado agregando un valor nuevo al final de cada lista:

```
[['peras', '20', 'Acme', 'AR'], ['bananas', '35', 'Zero', 'UY'], ['sandias', '45', 'Lion', 'BR']]
```

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
datos.append(codigo)
```

Pero el nuevo valor me lo agrega afuera de cada lista:

```
[['peras', '20', 'Acme'], 'AR', ['bananas', '35', 'Zero'], 'UY', ['sandias', '45', 'Lion'], 'BR']
```

Estoy usando Python 3.6
Podrian echarme una mano? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No está muy claro de dónde salen tus listas de datos, supongo que de consultas XPath a un documento XML. En todo caso, mi respuesta va en la línea de cómo juntar las listas que pretendes juntar, sin entrar en detalles sobre de dónde salen.

Básicamente asumo que tienes una lista con resultados parciales:

```py
print(datos)

# --- Salida ----
[['peras', '20', 'Acme'], ['bananas', '35', 'Zero'], ['sandias', '45', 'Lion']]
```

y otra con datos adicionales que son lo que quieres insertar:

```py
print(datos_adicionales)

# --- Salida ----
['AR', 'UY', 'BR']
```

Una forma de juntarlas como pretendes sería:

```
for sublista, dato_adicional in zip(datos, datos_adicionales):
   sublista.append(dato_adicional)
print(datos)

# --- Salida ----
[['peras', '20', 'Acme', 'AR'], ['bananas', '35', 'Zero', 'UY'], ['sandias', '45', 'Lion', 'BR']]
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo funciona muy bien, ahora estoy tratando de adaptarlo a mi codigo. Mis listas de datos salen de la respuesta de una API. Muchas gracias